# php file get content, search and display

Tags: php

I have some content it another website that i would like to
show my users, i use file get content function.

but i dont need to display the whole content, just two rows,
The current product and the next product.
the content is arranged with html tables.

my code:

```
   <?php
$url = "http://the second website.com";
$str = file_get_contents($url);

$lines = explode("<tr>", $str);

foreach ($lines as $newline) {
    echo '<tr>' . $newline . '</tr>'; -- This prints all lines.
}
?>
```

How to echo only the specific lines ?
My needed line are start with the strings "current product" and "next product".
Do i need to use an array ? or do in need to use a search string function ?

Thanks all.

Comment: I'd recommend you to loop through all the lines (as you are doing now) but `echo` them only, if the match a pattern that identifies the rows you need

Comment: You can use Simple Html dom http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ and parse and get whatever you want.

Comment: Show the `HTML` containing the lines "current product" and "next product"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with `preg_match_all` like this:

```
$table = <<<EOS
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td>1.2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2.1</td>
      <td>2.2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
EOS;

preg_match_all('/<tr.*?>(.*?)<\/tr>/si', $table, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td>1.2</td>

    [1] => 
      <td>2.1</td>
      <td>2.2</td>

)
```

You could also read about [PHP DOM Inspector](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with parsed content from other sites (like specific part of the DOM) then use a php library like PHP Simple HTML DOM, check it out here: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

They have a quick start demonstration, so it is easy to use for everyone.